# How to see all deleted questions of a particular user?

Tags: support

I've just run across 2 deleted questions from [this user](https://askubuntu.com/users/466702/akalank-prakash) in the last 10 minutes. (Example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691890/permission-denied-in-nano-how-to-solve-this) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691864/how-to-create-etc-x11-xorg-conf-file) for 10K+ rep users )

It ***seems*** he/she/it's gaming the system and deleting his/her/its questions when he/she/it gets an answer in the comments or when his question is duplicated.

*How can I investigate this user any further to check if he's using/abusing the system?*

Comment: I do not see any problems with that user. He asked two questions, got some comments that solved his issue and deleted the questions. It is not an abuse.

Comment: That's why "ab" was in between "()" and I use the word "seems"...  Until further investigation, we don't know if he's actually gaming the system or not... (edited for clarity anyway. thanks for the comment @Pilot6)

Comment: @Pilot6 Neither do I, but the user needs to understand that's (generally) against the rules. It wasn't a big deal in these cases, but we don't know if it did that in other cases (unlikely since they are a member since today, but still), and in general doing that with questions potentially useful with an answer in the comments or on the question is harmful, and it's against the rules.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if they delete enough of their posts won't they get locked out from posting?  I seem to remember that if you delete your own stuff too much you get locked out for a while.

Comment: @ThomasW. I think you're right - some sort of anti-ragequit system.

Comment: @ThomasW. Yup...  and this user is in this exact situation according to Seth.

Comment: Thought so, I think it's an anti abuse system too

Comment: Once this behaviour reaches a certain level, the system kicks in and moderators are notified.

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13752/is-it-not-done-to-clean-up-your-own-list-of-posted-answers

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Yeah, seen it already and upvoted already!  No need to beg for more upvotes!  **:P  ;-)**

Comment: Haha, honestly, I didn't notice (and I don't keep track on votes too closely here :) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of a user's deleted questions isn't publicly available data. But, as  [RolandiXor pointed out in the comments](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14625/how-to-see-all-deleted-questions-of-a-particular-user#comment25843_14625) if this behaviour continues the system either blocks the user from asking more questions, notifies the moderators, or both, depending on the exact behaviour happening.

Comment: You're overworked otherwise you would have answered this a long time ago...  ;-)